# MS Project : How to debug when "level all" freezes

Tags: ms-project-2016

I have a project with sub-projects which have sub-projects. I'm sharing the resources from one other project file.
I'm trying to level all the resources but MS Project freezes and it never ends.

How could I debug that and find a way to solve the problem ?

Answer (score 2):

I've managed to deal with my problem : 
I've changed the leveling option "Level without changing the end date of the project". I've unchecked it and now it works.

Too bad that MS Project checks it by default and doesn't alert if it can't solve the leveling because of it.

Anyway, if you have another hint to solve my problem, I'll study it.

Answer (score 1):

A master project whose subprojects are also master projects that are all sharing resources from yet another file? It is not at all surprising that MS Project would freeze when having to calculate across all that complexity.

Solution: Simply your schedules by removing a layer of subprojects and run the leveling on the most powerful computer you can.

Comment: Thank you for this hint. I've tried it, but it didn't change anything.